# none of command works after trying to add ~/.bash_profile

Tags: osx, bash-profile

I was trying to add `JAVA_HOME` in the path variable.
I downloaded Java JDK and done following:

- `nano ~/.bash_profile`
- added following lines and saved the file:

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin=$PATH
  ```
- `source ~/.bash_profile`

After that I tried to open bash file again using:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

It shows:

```
-bash: nano: command not found
```

I tried other commands too such as `brew doctor`, `curl`, `vim`, `java -version` etc. All of them shows command not found error.

What is the solution for this? How can I restore my system?

**Updated:** Solution that I used:

I run the following commands to set the standard default path that Mac OS uses in the command line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin=$PATH
```

should read

```
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

(note the `=` changing to `:` towards the end, and I also double-quoted the value for safety in case there are any spaces in any of the pathnames)

You will have to change that using the full path to the `nano` editor (`/usr/bin/nano` on macOS)

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

... and then restart your shell/terminal.  Using `source` on shell startup files is almost never a good idea as that would add to the existing `PATH` variable (and possibly to others as well) rather than modify a "clean" version of the variable, and it may have other interesting side-effects if things like `tmux` or `screen` are automatically started.

You could also temporarily get a sensible value for `PATH` so that you can repair the file with `nano` using

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

The `getconf PATH` command returns a `PATH` string that is supposed to cover all standard utilities.  On macOS, this includes the `nano` editor.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `nano` with an absolute path like

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

(I don't know where `nano` is located on your system.)

When adding `$JAVA_HOME` to `PATH` in your `.bash_profile` you have to use `:` instead of `=`

```
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```