# How to reset $PATH after accidentally setting it to something nonsense?

Tags: path

I'm on Mac OS X High Sierra. I was doing an scp command, repeated several times so I wanted to be clever and just set the variable `$IMAGE` for the image name and `$PATH` if I needed to add an extra path to it. Well, I set the `$PATH` variable to "page-attachments" so naturally no linux commands will work in the CLI now. I can't even try to redefine `$PATH`. Any command returns

> -bash: page-attachments: command not found

Is there a way for me to reset it to whatever it was? I can't `vim .bashrc` or .bash_profile because even vim doesn't work now. I'm not sure if it was `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or something else or what other repercussions there are.

Comment: new terminal ? logoff/logon ?

Comment: I just came back to delete my post. The variable was only defined for that tab, so using a new tab reset it. I know that's basic but it was my first time using variables in CLI and not in bash scripts.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496440/117549

Comment: Sometime Unix (or Mac OS for that matter) is forgiving ...

Answer (score 5):

You could use something along the lines of:

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

to use the full path to `getconf`, which will return a stock PATH value that you can use going forward.